# Display URL in Lower Case in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

My model has a category for a retailer--example - "Walmart"

All of the retailers in my database have been entered with the first letter capitalized.

I am trying to show a list of products by retailer on my site.

My url looks like so:

```
path('retailer-deals/<str:retailer>', deals_by_retailer, name='retailer'),
```

and my view looks like this:

```
def deals_by_retailer(request,retailer):
    retailer_deals = Deal.objects.filter(retailer__company=retailer).order_by('expired','-date_added')
    retailer = retailer
    return render(request, 'deals/deal_by_retailer.html', {'retailer_deals': retailer_deals, 'retailer': retailer})
```

So if i go to `retailer-deals/walmart` nothing shows up...

but of course `retailer-deals/Walmart` works fine

i might be being nitpicky--but i think it looks more professional with the lower case `walmart` and just in case someone goes to enter the uppercase version, i want to make sure it populates correctly

I did see someone mention a (?i) for a similar problem,

and i tried changing my path to this:

`path('(?i)retailer-deals/<str:retailer>', deals_by_retailer, name='retailer'),`

but that doesn't seem to work....and also, if i go to list the retailers with associated links--the generated url will still have the uppercase url..

Comment: While creating link, you can change cases or try slug field.

Comment: yeah--that's right--didn't think about that--then the only other issue i'm running into is the %20 for spaces..so maybe makes sense to enter a new slugify field i think

Comment: What is `retailer = retailer`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [iexact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-iexact) in your filter, A case-insensitive exact match.

```
retailer_deals = Deal.objects.filter(
        field_name__iexact=retailer).order_by('expired','-date_added')
```

As many of other people suggest,
the best way is to do such query with slug, so you would have:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
import uuid 
class YourModel(mdoels):
     slug = models.SlugField()
     name = models.CharField(max_mength=100)

     # override the save method to have slug automatically generated
     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if self.pk is None:
             slug = slugify(self.name)
             while self.__class__.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
                  slug = "%s-%s" % (slug,str(uuid.uuid4())[:5])
             self.slug = slug
         super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

your url would become:

```
path('retailer-deals/<slug:slug>', deals_by_retailer, name='retailer'),
```

and your views:

```
def deals_by_retailer(request,slug):
    retailer_deals = Deal.objects.filter(retailer__slug=slug)
    ''' codes '''
```

Comment: yes! I updated my answer to let you know how to use it with `slug`, how to **generate one**, and how to make sure that the **slug is unique**

Comment: Awesome thanks!  If I already have a bunch of records saved in my retailer field, will that automatically slugify my fields or would I need to do it manually?

Comment: you can remove that line `if self.pk is None:` and loop through all your records, then call the save method, the slug will automatically be generated for each one inside the loop, my code above will do the trick.. i.e : `for obj in Record.objects.all(): obj.save()` don't forget to remove `if self.pk is None`, put it back once you done

Comment: @Lemayzeur you have a typo `slug = slugigy(self.name)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer your question indirectly because I think doing an `iexact` filter in your routes is a code smell.  It also opens you up to people typing paths like `retailer-deals/WaLmArT` which would then break if you switched to a setup with slugs down the road for simplicity.

The best practice is to use slugs to define URLs for longevity.  Things like spaces, punctuation, and non-ASCII character encoding used in names can make for ugly or invalid URLs.

You can use a slug in `urlpatterns` like:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('widgets/<slug:slug>/', views.foo),
]
```

There's more info in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#example) for this example.

Django has a built-in [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) model field for this use case.  You can also [prepopulate it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) in the Django admin from another field such as title.

```
class WidgetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

Comment: Thanks Taylor—I had started to thing about adding a slug as well and I think your comments are absolutely on point.

Comment: @JohnRogerson Happy to help!  I haven't written Django in a couple years, and after working with other frameworks, it's easy to forget all of the niceties that come included out of the box with Django :).  By the way, the book *Two Scoops of Django* is incredible and distills a lot more info if you'd like to see more best practices.

Comment: Yes I have that book —it’s one of my favorites for Django!

Comment: You're totally right, I just wanted to point @JohnRogerson to the right way for case-insensitive query, but slug is the best way by far

Comment: @Lemayzeur For sure — I agree personally. I think having both your direct answer and my indirect answer are helpful to future people stumbling upon this question with a query like OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is find.

```
path('retailer-deals/<str:retailer>', deals_by_retailer, name='retailer'),
```

your `<str:retailer>` is some arguments that your request get.

It means it's not fix one. You can attach anything you want - like `pk`, `slug`, `title`, `uuid` and so on.

So In your situation, if you want to use lowercase in your url, you can add your own slug to your model, and pass it to your url.

i.e.

Your urls will be

```
path('retailer-deals/<str:slug>', deals_by_retailer, name='retailer'),
```

And your views will be

```
def deals_by_retailer(request,slug):
    retailer_deals = Deal.objects.filter(retailer__slug=slug).order_by('expired','-date_added')
    retailer = retailer
    return render(request, 'deals/deal_by_retailer.html', {'retailer_deals': retailer_deals, 'retailer': retailer})
```

Also you have to add slug to your model

```
# maybe your Retailer model
Retailter(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name="slug",
    )
    ...

    # You can save slug automaticall when saving 
    # using __save__ or signals
```

> Using slug in url is good way for many reasons (url not support white space, and many other chars, but your `company` fields can get them). So you can make slug from your company - unique and well-fit to url.