# How to auto generate slug from my Album model in django 2.0.4

Tags: python, django, slug

I have an Album field with a list of Songs

```
 class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title               

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist
```

I would like to know how to generate slugs from the album title. I am following a tutorial which is using django 1.8 which uses regular expressions to implement this task. But from looking through the documentation they have introduced a  more simpler approach ('').
So can you help explain how I can implement it for a beginner to understand not only in this context but if possible across board.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had answered a similar question, check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244541/5644965)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django autogenerates the slug from the string object you pass to the slug field.

```
# Import slugify to generate slugs from strings
from django.utils.text import slugify 

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.album_title)
        super(Album, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title    


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.song_title)
        super(Song, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist
```

Comment: this answer generates a new slug if the object title is modified, which can cause links to break. It's safer to check if a slug exists before generating one

Comment: @GEV How to do that?

Comment: @DerekPK You can just add a check to the save method (i.e. if not self.slug); I suggested an edit. But I think your answer using signals should work as well and might even be better. Is there a reason why not to just use your answer?

Answer (score 1):

To use signals,
Here is the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEX50LJrFuU) where I found the solution for this

---

*models.py*

import these stuff

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
```

---

Add this under your model.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title   

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Store)
def store_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = slugify(instance.song_title)
```

> Make sure it's under the class and the def,
> otherwise you will get an error

Answer (score 1):

```
**models.py**
from    django.db   import  models
from    django.utils    import  timezone
from    django.contrib.auth.models  import  User
class   Post(models.Model):
                STATUS_CHOICES  =   (
                                ('draft',   'Draft'),
                                ('published',   'Published'),
                )
                title   =   models.CharField(max_length=250)
                slug    =   models.SlugField(max_length=250,                                                                unique_for_date='publish')
                author  =   models.ForeignKey(User,
                                                                                                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                                                                                            related_name='blog_posts')
                body    =   models.TextField()
                publish =   models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
                created =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
                updated =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
                status  =   models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                                                                                                        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                                                                                                                        default='draft')
                class   Meta:
                                ordering    =   ('-publish',)
   
                def __str__(self):
                                return  self.title 
   **admin.py**
        @admin.register(Post)
        class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            list_display=('title',  'slug', 'author',   'publish',status')
            list_filter=('status',  'created',  'publish',  'author')
            search_fields=('title', 'body')
            prepopulated_fields={'slug':    ('title',)}
            raw_id_fields=('author',)
            date_hierarchy='publish'
```

**The above models.py and admin.py**
when you write your post title instantly your slug automatically populated you dont write slug